# Socket io, Try multiple URLs to establish connection after "connect_error"

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have an app with divided code (client / server). On the client side, I'd like socket io to attempt multiple URLs (one at a time) until it connects successfully.

Here's my code:

```
const BAD_HOST = "http://localhost:8081";
const LOCAL_HOST = "http://localhost:8080";
const SOCKET_CONFIG = {
  upgrade: false,
  transports: ["websocket"],
  auth: { ... }, // Trimmed for brevity
  extraHeaders: { ... }, // Trimmed for brevity
};

let socket = io(BAD_HOST, SOCKET_CONFIG); // This connects fine when I use LOCAL_HOST

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(err); 
  socket = io(LOCAL_HOST, SOCKET_CONFIG); // DOES NOT WORK
});

socket.on("connect", () => { ... } // Trimmed for brevity
```

In short, when I try to reassign the value for socket to a new io connection, it seems to retain the old, failed connection. My browser continues to throw 'connect_error' messages from the bad url:
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:`

I checked but couldn't find any official documentation on this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think an approach is already discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22722710/656708

Essentially you have an array of URLs, which in your case would be:

```js
const socketServerURLs = ["http://localhost:8081","http://localhost:8080"];
```

and then iterate over them, trying to initiate a socket connection, like this:

```js
// something along these lines
socketServerURLs.forEach((url) => { 
  // ...
  socket.connect(url, socketConfiguration, (client) => {});
  // ...
}
```

Then again, I don't know what a `BAD_HOST` entails. Assuming that you mean that a connection to that host failed, how would you know that without actually trying to connect to it?

Comment: This is a test where BAD_HOST is intentionally failing. There is no host at that address. BAD_HOST exists to test the functionality of the question. The question exists because in reality I have a project with multiple hosts, any one of which might be down, but I want the client to continue trying others. The solution you gave would open multiple connections on successes.